# Where is the Google web album service on API Console?

Tags: picasa

I want to register Google Web Album API to upload image, but I don't see the Google Web Album Data in the Services of API Console.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you find this answer? I am also in same situation.

Comment: @Mvcdev Still not but I think the Google Web Album Data is enable by default.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Picasa Web Albums Data API developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol) section "**Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0**":-

> Activate the Picasa Web Albums Data API in the Services pane of the
>   Google APIs Console. (If it isn't listed in the Console, then skip
>   this step.)

The application then needs to request an access *scope* , described in a further document [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).  In my case the application is going to run as a service with no user interaction, so the relevant section is **Service accounts**.

I'll post some code up when/if I get this working.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that you don't explicitly enable the Picasa Web Albums Data API in the google console. However, I had a problem where my Picasa access stopped working. I concluded it was due to a recent change how google handles apps. My app was created in the old console (https://code.google.com/apis/console). I created a new project in the new console and used that clientId/clientSecret for my OAuth, then my picasa access started working again (with no code change). Full details posted here: http://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/522/Google-OAuth2-with-PicasaWeb.html