# Unable to find Picasa Web Albums Data API in developer console

Tags: android, scope, google-plus, picasa

I am trying to enable the Picasa Web Albums Data API on the developer console. The problem is I couldn't find it. When I went to the API Explorer to test the scope query, I couldn't find that API either [https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Google web album service on API Console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565278/where-is-the-google-web-album-service-on-api-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it the API is too old to support the developer console or the APIs explorer. Once you have a client ID/key you can just start using the API as documented.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I concluded it was due to a recent change how google handles apps. My app was created in the old console (https://code.google.com/apis/console). I created a new project in the new console and used that clientId/clientSecret for my OAuth, then my picasa access started working again. Full details posted here: http://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/522/Google-OAuth2-with-PicasaWeb.html